# Finding an upper bound for an expression involving exponential

Tags: exponential-function, upper-lower-bounds

Given $T_{2} < T_{1}$, how to prove that for $t>0$ $$\sqrt{\left(1-e^{\frac{-t}{T_1}}\right)^{2} + e^{\frac{-2t}{T_2}}} \leq 1$$

Any hints to get started would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can write what you want using this equivalences
$$
\begin{align}
& \sqrt{\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{T_{1}}}\right)^2+e^{-\frac{2t}{T_{2}}}} \leq 1 \Longleftrightarrow \left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{T_{1}}}\right)^2+e^{-\frac{2t}{T_{2}}} \leq1 \Longleftrightarrow 1 - 2e^{-\frac{t}{T_{1}}}+ e^{-\frac{2t}{T_{1}}} + e^{-\frac{2t}{T_{2}}} \leq 1 \\ 
&\Longleftrightarrow  2e^{-\frac{t}{T_{1}}} - e^{-\frac{2t}{T_{1}}} - e^{-\frac{2t}{T_{2}}} \geq 0.\\
\end{align}
$$
So you can set $f(t) = 2e^{-\frac{t}{T_{1}}} - e^{-\frac{2t}{T_{1}}} - e^{-\frac{2t}{T_{2}}}$, since $f(0)=0$, you only need to prove that $f'(t) \geq 0$ for all $t>0$ and you get what you want.